# Android Studio - URL string

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent, mp4

So I'm pretty new to the whole Android Studio thing and I've been using the internet to help me with a lot of the things I am doing and needed help on something.

I'm not sure if it's possible to connect this to either a string or an SQL database but I have a Main Layouts with a bunch of buttons that allow me to click on them and choose what external player I would like to use to watch the video. In my MainActivity java class, this is how it finds the button.

```
case R.id.button3:
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);            
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://videoname.mp4"), "video/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an External Player"));
    break;"
```

I wanted to know if "http://videoname.mp4" url can be connected to like a string where I can always update or change the URL instead of manually going to find the URL in the MainActivity java and changing it. As of now I have to manually do it but a different way to do it would be helpful.

I'm sorry if it's all confusing, but if you know, please let me know as soon as.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need write your string URL :

open your directory folder `/res/values/strings.xml` -> write your string : `<string name="yourStringName>yourStringURL</string>`. to use your string do this

1. `getContext().getString(R.string.yourStringName)`  in `fragment`
2. `getString(R.string.yourStringName)` in `Activity`

or you can write directly on your code, put your cursor on your string, then press key `alt + enter` choose `extract string resource` fill the `resource name` with your string name

wherever you need to use it, just do point 1 or 2. also in your `Intent`

hope this help you, never stop learning!

Comment: Thank you! I did the Activity code you gave and it worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add it to strings.xml in your project. That is the recommended way of using strings anyway.

Comment: How would I put the string inside the intent? I'm stuck there.